# How do I upload a background image?

Tags: theming, media

I want to insert a background image in the *IBM API Connect* theme. 
I first googled, and I found how to insert an image in a node; then I downloaded the [Background Images](https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image), the [Background Images Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image_formatter), and the [ImageCache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) modules, but to no avail.

I found out the CSS for it.

```
   body #main-wrapper { 
   background-color: #FFFFFF !important;  
   background-image: url('sites/all/BackgroundWallpapers/pink1.jpg') 
   !important;
   background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
   background-attachment: scroll !important;
   background-position: left top !important;
   background-size: cover !important;
   -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
   -moz-background-size: cover !important;
   -o-background-size: cover !important;
    }
```

I don't know how to insert a URL/path for the background image in the  background-image attribute. Where do I store the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store image in your drupal theme.

for example, you are using custom theme then you can store image in 
project_name/sites/all/themes/custom_theme/images/image_name.jpg

And reference this path in your css file of your theme as below

background-image: url(../images/image_name.jpg);

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81571/discussion-on-answer-by-amol-shetkar-how-do-i-upload-a-background-image).

Answer (score 0):

As for the Background Image Formatter, what you want to do is:

- Determine which element should get the background image you want to print
- Provide said element with a custom CSS class
- In the CSS selector field of the Background Image Formatter settings, input your custom CSS class, then setup the other parameters

It can be ANY valid CSS selector, and you can use token replacement, providing you with things like the current NID allowing it to be used in a view with custom text where you dynamically create your class in the text and call it from the formatter.

You can also provide it with pseudo selector allowing you to put the background image on a ::after or a :hover for additional control